# How to change the scale of RectTransfrom in script unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i can't find a way to change the scale of the rectTransform in script,
[from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xCFg.png) , i want to make a script that makes the y-scale change and attach it to the gameobject

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're struggling because you can't set the .y value specifically -- it is read only.  But you can create a new Vector3 value, use the current scale of the rectTransform for the x & z values, and pass in what you want for the y value.

```
float yScale = 1.35f;
targetTransform.localScale = new Vector3(targetTransform.localScale.x, yScale, targetTransform.localScale.z);
```